# Custom Alphabetic CSV Sorting (Turkish Characters)

Tags: tables, sorting, datatool

I have a *CSV* list with *Turkish* names and ages.

1. I want to sort it in ascending alphabetical order. However, *Turkish* characters seem to break the sorting.
2. Another question would how to insert line numbers for the list if possible.

Also, I use *Turkish* characters (çğıöşü) in *CSV* file, I got errors,
this is why I had to use the *LaTeX* codes in the *CSV* file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Age
\c{S}eng\"{u}l,17
\c{C}etin,32
H\"{u}seyin,23
B\"{u}lent,41
Ay\c{s}e,27
Ba\c{s}ak,37
\end{filecontents*}

\pagestyle{empty}

\DTLloaddb[keys={Name,Age}]{data}{data.csv}
\DTLsort{Name=ascending}{data}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Turkish Alphabet}: abc\c{c}defgh{\i}ijklmno\"{o}prs\c{s}tu\"{u}vyz

{\tiny
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Name &
    \bfseries Age \\
  \midrule
  \DTLforeach{data}{%
    \pname=Name,\pAge=Age}{%
    \pname & \pAge \\
  }
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison handlers provided by `datatool` only perform character code comparisons. TeX doesn't provide a convenient interface to general locale-related data, such as the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository. Instead you need to pre-process the data using an external tool that can access that type of information.

The [`datatooltk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) application provides a way of both sorting according to a particular locale and saving the data into a form that can be quickly input by `\DTLloaddbtex` provided by the `datatool` package.

For example, with `data.csv` (UTF-8):

```
Name,Age
Şengül,17
Çetin,32
Hüseyin,23
Bülent,41
Ayşe,27
Başak,37
```

Then the file `data.dbtex` can be created using:

```
datatooltk --csv-encoding UTF-8 --tex-encoding UTF-8 --sort Name --sort-locale tr --csv data.csv --output data.dbtex
```

This imports the data from the CSV file, sorts according to the `Name` field using the locale identified by the language tag `tr` (Turkish), and saves the sorted data to the file `data.dbtex`, which can now be loaded into the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty}

\DTLloaddbtex{\mydata}{data.dbtex}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Turkish Alphabet}: abc\c{c}defgh{\i}ijklmno\"{o}prs\c{s}tu\"{u}vyz

{\tiny
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Name &
    \bfseries Age \\
  \midrule
  \DTLforeach{\mydata}{%
    \pname=Name,\pAge=Age}{%
    \pname & \pAge \\
  }
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

The `data.dbtex` file only needs rebuilding if the data is changed. This has the supplementary benefit of speeding up the document build.

[image: Turkish Alphabet: abcçdefghıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz Name Age Ayşe 27 Başak 37 Bülent 41 Çetin 32 Hüseyin 23 Şengül 17]

You can set up the default values for options like `--csv-encoding`, `--tex-encoding` and `--sort-locale` in `datatooltk`'s GUI mode.